# Multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

How to get stored the value entered by user in multidimensional array

Comment: read through http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is C.

```
int arr[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
int m01 = arr[0][1];
printf("%d\n", m01);
```

The above output will be 2.

It is important also to not confuse `int **` with `int [][]`.  They are very much different.